# react keyboard navigation accessibility

Tags: reactjs, typescript, keyboard-navigation

I want to add the keyboard navigation with (`arrow up, arrow down, tab and enter`) to my select component, so the user can navigate within the items in the select box using the keyboard, how can this be done?

```
export function SelectComponent({
...
}: SelectProps) {
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
const [focusedIndex, setFocusedIndex] = useState("");
const searchResults = useMemo(() => {
if (!search) return options;

    return options.filter(item =>
      item.value.toString().toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
    );

}, [options, search]);
const keyboardNavigation = (event: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
if (event.key === "ArrowDown") {
setIsOpen(true);
    }
    if (event.key === "ArrowUp") {
      ////Here to add the code
    }
    if (event.key === "Escape") {
     ////Here to add the code
    }
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
     ////Here to add the code
    }

};

return (
<div onKeyDown={event => keyboardNavigation(event)}>
<input onClick={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)} value={search} onChange={event => setSearch(event?.target.value)}/>
<div>
{searchResults.map((option, index) => {
return (
<div tabIndex={0} key={option.label} onClick={() => { setIsOpen(false); setSearch(option.value.toString());}}>{option.value}</div>);
})}
</div></div>);}
```